# Android Beacon Library Eddystone Telemetry. Temperature

Tags: android, temperature, eddystone, telemetry, beacon

Android Vers. > 4.3
Standard Android Beacon Library
Estimote Beacons.
Eddystone-UID package
Telemetry package.

I'm trying to read the temp sensor transmission from the Telemetry package of a Eddystone-UID package transmission. I can successfully read the beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(2) data for the temperature transmission as per Eddystone [Telemetry] expamples in Android Beacon Library. This data prints as a 4 or 5 digit number depending on the temp.

I'm informed by same that the beacon temp sensor transmits a 8:8 fixed point number ... reading beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(2) and then dividing by 256 I get the temperature reading in Celsius. However as soon as temp crosses 0 degC into the negative I get large discrepancies. Research among the forums seems to indicate that its to do with signed 8:8 fixed notation math and conversion to decimal. Although I understand the 8:8 fixed point notation concept I cant seem to find a reference on how to read a negative fixed point and convert to negative degC using the Android Beacon Library methods.

[Note: Estimote's Android SDK and their beacon app had the same problem ... they fixed this by updating their SDK ... I'm using Android Library and not Estimote SDK]

Guidance will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below is used to convert the encoded Eddystone telemetry temperature field to degrees celsius.  This is taken from the [Locate Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate), which also uses the [Android Beacon Library](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/collections/all/products/eddystone-devkit?gclid=Cj0KEQjw5MGxBRDiuZm2icXX2-sBEiQA619bq9gpdmoZqsSs3tuPJO1LuxRXCJhGn0RhDs5JDM98C8AaAsaK8P8HAQ).  This code has  been tested with Eddystone beacons from Radius Networks.

```
long unsignedTemp = (beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(2) >> 8);
double temperature = unsignedTemp > 128 ? 
    unsignedTemp - 256 : 
    unsignedTemp +(beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(2) & 0xff)/256.0;
```

You can try this conversion formula with the beacons you have on hand.  If you find that it doesn't work, also try the Locate app to make sure you see the same thing.  If that is the case, it may be that the encoded value is not fully compliant with the Eddystone spec.

Comment: Worked well. Tested with Estimote beacon. temp range +25 to -22 degC. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method with *davidgyoung* conversion formula to retrieve temperature from a beacon, while casting to a float with two decimals:

```
public static float getTemperatureFromBeacon(Beacon beacon) {
    long unsignedTemp = (beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(2) >> 8);
    double temperatureDouble = unsignedTemp > 128 ?
            unsignedTemp - 256 :
            unsignedTemp + (beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(2) & 0xff) / 256.0;
    float temperature = (float) Math.round(temperatureDouble * 100) / 100;
    return temperature;
}
```